# windows screen saver as android live wallpaper

Tags: android, windows, live-wallpaper

I would like to know if there is a way to process a .scr file (windows screen saver file) to make an android live wallpaper from it? I searched a lot on google  about it without luck.

Does any have an idea of how to do this or where I can find useful information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .scr file is simply a Windows executable with a different extension. It is build from x86 instructions which are completely incompatible with Android.

Even if you were to recompile the screen saver from source, the programming for the Windows API will be completely different from Android.

This is simply not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to run an .SCR using WINE...

WINE on Android

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1258506

.SCR under WINE

http://wiki.winehq.org/ScreenSavers

Comment: I'm continually amazed by the things people do.

Comment: The ubuntu wine available for android, this is really cool and useful information, now I'm having fun with the guide. thanks for sharing that link.